# What is Magento PWA we should learn in 2021?

Tags: magento2

I want to learn new skills like Magento PWA.

Can you advise me on some framework to make Magento PWA?

Please text some reason for using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to a PWA solution, you could also have a look at the [Hyvä theme](https://hyva.io) for Magento 2. Compared to Luma theme Hyvä provides a modern frontend-stack with TailwindCSS and AlpineJS.

If it has to be PWA, you could have a look at [Magento PWA Studio](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/) or [vuestorefront](https://www.vuestorefront.io/pwa-for-magento). The choice would then be React vs. vue.js depending on your personal preference.

Comment: Yep, I have heard about the Hyva theme, I'll try it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Progressive Web App is a hybrid of a website and a mobile application. PWAs focus on establishing a dynamic approach to engage with consumers in addition to outstanding user experiences. Users may browse eCommerce stores via mobile-optimized versions of the website rather than installing native applications on their mobile devices. [Magento PWA services](https://www.yereone.com/magento-pwa-development) are totally game-changer for the eCommerce industry in 2021. It doesn't need installation which to save the customer time, has a fully responsive design, gives the opportunity to send real-time push notifications, has URLs, and can be crawled and indexed by search engines, they are served through HTTPS ensuring safety in content delivery and content interaction.

Comment: Yep, The game has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Dylon Nago you can check this link.
https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/?_ga=2.220583196.587258091.1632408133-2072401441.1625738549

https://onilab.com/blog/how-to-build-a-pwa-storefront-magento-2-a-detailed-guide/

This will help you to understand the basic concept of PWA and its advantages over website.

Thank YOu